# В ответ на fetch запрос получаю 403 ошибку, но и сообщение от cервера получаю, как его вывести в catch?

Tags: javascript, fetch, try-catch

Среда выполнения React. Отправляю запрос:

```
fetch('https://my-site.ru/bla/bla-bla/get-token', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
  })
})
.then(res => {

  if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300 ) {
      return res;
  } else {
     let error = new Error(res.statusText);
     error.response = res;
     throw error
  }

  })
  .then((res) => {

    if (res.headers['content-type'] !== "application/json; charset=UTF-8") {
      let error = new Error('Некорректный ответ от сервера');
      error.response = res;
      throw error
  } else func(res.data)

}).catch(e => {
console.log(e) //выведет 'Error [object promice]'
console.log(e.message) // Выведет '[object promice]'
})
```

Если Имя или Пароль введены не верно, сервер возвращает 403 и сообщение на вкладке DevTooll о том, что именно не так. Но я никак не могу вывести это сообщение в catch. Я попадаю в catch при 403 ошибке, но не пойму как достать сообщение от сервера.

Вот так выглядит на вкладке "ответ" в Devtools

```
{"success":false,"statusCode":403,"code":"invalid_username","message":"\u041e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430: \u0418\u043c\u044f \u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044f asd \u043d\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u0440\u0435\u0433\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e \u043d\u0430 \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0435. \u0415\u0441\u043b\u0438 \u0432\u044b \u0437\u0430\u0431\u044b\u043b\u0438 \u0438\u043c\u044f \u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044f, \u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435 \u0432\u043c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e \u043d\u0435\u0433\u043e \u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441 email.","data":[]}
```

Вот код ответа в браузере на вкладке "предварительный просмотр"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как достать этот объект, что на скриншоте и вывести message?

Заголовки запроса и ответа
[image: Заголовки и оветы]

Объекта ответа полученный в catch
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раз console.log(e.message) выведет'[object promice]' в консоли, думаю надо копать в сторону того, что нужно обратиться к этому промису и дождаться его выполнения. У меня мало знаний, это лишь предположение

Comment: а на вкладке "заголовки" что? Там скорее всего 200. Вам скорее всего приходит json с информацией. Её и обрабатывайте.

Comment: В заголовке овтета на вкладке "заголовки" так же приходит 403 код. Продолжаю копать в сторону обработки самого промиса возвращенного catch

Comment: Я сбит с толку. Даже если в catch просто сделать return e и добавить следующий then, то этот then все равно ввозвратит промис

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в чём проблема.
Всему виной .json() .then и поточность.
Сразу, рабочий код:

```
  fetch('https://my-site.ru/bla/blabla/token', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response.json();
  } else {
      return response.json() //Парсим ответ
      .then(result => { //Далаем занесение в catch ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ПАРСИНГА!
        let error = new Error(result.status);
        error.response = result ;
        throw error
      })
  }
  })
```

У меня пока маловато знаний, что бы подробно обьяснить, но тут что то связанное с поточностью процессов. Просто информация уходила в catch до того как была распарсена, поэтому видимо, надо обязательно использовать then после .json()

Вот это обсуждение очень в тему: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('https://my-site.ru/bla/bla-bla/get-token', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
  })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  if (res.statusCode == 403) console.log(res.message);
})
```

Comment: Не работает. Я поставил debugger на входе и посмотрел, что приходит в res на этапе выполнения. Там вообще пустое поле statusText. Не понимаю, откуда вообще тогда формируется объект на скриншоте. В какой момент создается этот злополучный промис и как с ним взаимодействовать

Comment: приложите скриношты заголовков и ответа в основной вопрос

Comment: Приложил скришнот заголовков и ответов

Comment: Продолжу искать решение, как найду дам ответ

Comment: Я смог получить ответ запроса в catch такой, какой получал на входе. При формировании объекта Error я просто закинул не текст ответа, а весь ответ: new Error(res). В catch: console.log(error.response) 
Получил объект ответа(добавил скриншот)
Но в объекте, что я получил всё равно нет того сообщения, что выдаёт сервер, которое я вижу в DevTools

Comment: Полагаю, что код который я прикладывал в начальном вопросе, который мне показывает вкладка "ответ" в DevTools не предназначен для приема и работы с ним в приложении. Ответ который я вижу в DevTools и ответ который я вижу на входе в первый then поставив там debugger совершенно разные. Проверяю информацию

Comment: Вообще это очень странное поведение сервера. В случае неправильной пары он должен был отправить ответ со статусом 200 и пояснениями. А при статусе 403 вороде бы вообще не должно быть развернутого сообщения